# What is the maximum baud rate achieved in raspberry pi 4b

Tags: signal

What is the maximum baud rate achieved in raspberry pi 4b for serial communication?

I want to use RPI for communicating with PC(win, linux),Want to acheive maximum speed through USB communication. I used ttyGS0 in rpi.
Please let me know any further information required to answer

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Why don't you try it and see? Actual performance will depend on your code.

Comment: I have edited my question.

Answer (score 1):

I know people have used the UART serial link at 4 Mbps.

I2C is limited to about 400 kbps.

SPI will probably work at 16 Mbps plus.

The maximum will depend on the electrical connections made between the Pi and external circuitry.

Answer (score 0):

Terms like "maximum", fastest, best etc. are meaningless, or at best opinion based.

If you want to achieve an objective, **ask a definite Question**.
The best™ solution to any problem is the one that works.

PS If you want a fast serial **DO NOT** use the mini UART - after all the Pi4 has 6 UART.